# replaceregexp to trim not working properly in Netbeans

Tags: regex, ant

I'm trying to to a trim to some values using replaceregexp. Everything looks great when I try it in software like EditPad Pro.

Here's a sample of what I want to accomplish:

```
mf.version.impl = 2.01.00  
mf.version.spec= 2.01.00
```

**Notice the extra spaces after the last digit.**

Then I'm using this pattern:

```
[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[ ]*
```

But it doesn't work in Netbeans.

Here's my ant command for it:

```
<!--If postfix is empty, remove the empty space-->
    <replaceregexp file="../Xinco/nbproject/project.properties"
                   match="mf.version.spec?=?[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[ ]*"
                   replace="mf.version.spec = ${version_high}.${version_mid}.${version_low}"
                   byline="false"/>
    <replaceregexp file="../Xinco/nbproject/project.properties"
                   match="mf.version.impl?=?[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+[ ]*"
                   replace="mf.version.impl = ${version_high}.${version_mid}.${version_low}"
                   byline="true"/>
```

**${version_high}.${version_mid}.${version_low} are variables already defined that correspond to 2.01.00 respectively.**

It results in

```
mf.version.impl = 2.01.00 
mf.version.spec = 2.01.00
```

**Notice one extra space after the last digit.**

I did debug the ant calls and it seems like the above command is not executing like a match didn't occur.

Any idea?

Comment: for one, you should escape the dots: `\.`. This is working for you purely by chance :)

Comment: I don't know anything about ant, but this makes little sense... `?` works on the one character before it, so you can match `mf.version.imp2c01d00`, and don't leave room for spaces. Can this work for you `^mf.version.impl\s*=.*$` ? this only checks the beginning of the linem and match throgh the end.

Comment: I noticed that also. Is already removed. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Write an answer with ^mf.version.impl\s*=.*$ so I can award it the answer! 

BTW can explain how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care about the value, you don't have to match it explicitly. Try:

```
^mf\.version\.impl\s*=.*$
```

Meaning:

- `^` - start of the line (on multiline mode)
- `mf\.version\.impl` - the string "mf.version.impl" literally, with the dots escaped.
- `\s*` - zero or more spaces
- `.*` - anything else (we can ignore the version, since you change it with a constant), all the way through to the...
- `$` - end of the line

#### Bonus track:

Looking at the [specs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html), it looks like you can catch both lines with a single regex (not sure it works though):

```
^(mf\.version\.(impl|spec))\s*=.*$
```

and the replace rule:

```
replace="\1 = ${version_high}.${version_mid}.${version_low}"
```

This will replace `\1` with the value it captured before, so again, you only need a single rule. (for trivia, usually `$1` is used in replaces, but not here)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably escape your .'s and use a capture group

e.g. (Perl regex for example)

```
s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[ ]*/$1/
```